# Two counts in sql but in separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause

I would like to carry out two counts within one sql statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(UserID) AS STAFF
FROM User_Role
WHERE(RoleID <> 1)

UNION

SELECT COUNT(UserID) AS STUDENTS
FROM User_Role AS User_Role_1
WHERE (RoleID = 1)
```

The above code works but outputs like this:

```
Staff

7

6
```

However i would like it too output in seperate coloumns like:

```
Staff   Students
7          6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT sum(case when roleid<>1 then 1 else 0 end) AS STAFF,
       sum(case when roleid=1 then 1 else 0 end) AS STUDENTS
FROM User_Role
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do this simply by adding the boolean expression:

```
SELECT SUM(RoleID <> 1) as STAFF, SUM(RoleID = 1) as Students
FROM User_Role;
```

This happens to be an extension to MySQL that I like -- many languages treat booleans as integers in a numeric context.